# Query for installed application value shown in HKCU?

Tags: registry, sccm, wql

I want to make a collection displaying computers with a certain application installed.
Usually this is done with a query similar to :

```
    select * from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64 on
 SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.DisplayName = "SoftwareDisplayName"
```

Which works fine for software which are listed in :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

However in this case, it's for Microsoft Teams and the registry key is actually not in HKLM, it's in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Teams
```

Is it at all possible to make a query for that ? Or I will have to create a custom script to check those computers?
What is the best strategy here?
Much appreciated.

Comment: All the inventories of sccm run with the system account so they ignore all user specific keys. What could be possibly is to utilize a Compliance Setting. Those allow for checks on a HKCU key and it is possible to create a collection based on the compliance status. Is this an option?

Comment: Yes I now realize this is the best way, thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

Easier if you do this via CM Pivot or create a baseline configuration and have it run a powershell script to find the registry key